# Expressions in Verilog module instantiations

Tags: verilog, synthesis

If I have the following verilog module definition:

```
module foo (
  input a,
  output b
  );

  assign b = !a;

endmodule
```

And then I instantiate it within another module like so

```
module bar (
  input c,
  output d
  );

  foo foo0 (
    .a(c),
    .b(!d) //note the not operator
  );

endmodule
```

I looked at the EBNF syntax definition for Verilog and it showed expressions as valid arguments for port assignment.
Will this do what I want (i.e. act as a passthrough—outputting c)? Or does verilog not allow operators other than concatenation for port assignment?

I realize this example is contrived, but my project has a decent amount of code so I didn't want to upload/explain all of it unless necessary.

Comment: What happened when you ran a simulation of this code?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I did not; I suppose I probably should've

Comment: @ElliotAlderson alright I attempted to simulate it with Verilator; that failed when the ! operator was present and succeeded when not present (although it didn't do what I wanted obviously). I also attempted to use XST to synthesize the files and it failed as well. Looks like I should just make a temporary wire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is legal for input port connections, but output ports can only be connected to nets and/or variables, or a concatenation of those. See section *23.3.3.3 Port connection rules for nets with built-in net types* of the 1800-2017 LRM.